# How would I use the page-id number to alter the CSS of a woocommerce page?

Tags: css, woocommerce

I'm using CSS Hero which makes it easy for the element to break down.

On one page the wrapper, which bleeds over to other templates, shows this:

`html>body>#wrapper>#main>#content>div`

Since I only want the changes to be for this element on this page what would I do? I tried this:

`.page-id-89 .html>body>#wrapper>#main>#content>div`

Unfortunately, this did not work.

Comment: you can apply your css like this `body.page-id-89>#wrapper>#main>#content>div`. WordPress always assign `page-id` class to body tag.

Comment: Thx. Let me try that and if Ill report back. Thx again.

Comment: ************* I just tried it and it does not work. Any other possible solutions? Thx.

Comment: Its the blog template for Woocommerce. Here is the page capture image. Trying to drop the blog contents so that the logo text line in yellow box wont be run into it...  https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bkhtw4aysseglh/image.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Please try this one `.page-id-89 #main #content div.`